# How to determine direction of rotation in CSS3 transitions?

Tags: css

I'd like to rotate an object from -180 degrees to 180 degrees via CSS3 transforms and transitions. This works fine, but I'd like to control the direction of rotation. How to determine if it will be going clockwise or counter clockwise?

Comment: I think you will need to set a mid-point in your animation. I haven't seen anything that lets you specify which way the rotation goes.

Comment: So that's via css3 animation properties you mean? Yes, that's what I also thought, but I'd like to do it just with simple css3 transition and transform properties, if at all possible.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

0 .. 180 is clockwise, 0 .. -180 is counterclockwise. So, positive number rotates clockwise, negative - other way around. You can also keep increasing/decreasing the number to continue rotation, the browser will remove additional 360s.

I created an example of how to rotate:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.rotatedDiv {
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(1deg);
}

</style>

<body>
<div class="rotatedDiv" onclick="this.style.webkitTransform='rotate(-100deg)'">
This div will do a spin when clicked!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

First we display rotated div. When you click on it, it will rotate. Depending on the value - negative or positive it will rotate counter-clockwise or clockwise.

Comment: But what if you want a transition between 30 and 40 degrees, only counter-clockwise?

Comment: Thanks. In the end I came up with a solution, triggered by your example. Degrees are not limited by a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 360. You can also specify -720 for example. This way you can control clockwise and counter-clockwise movement.

Comment: But what if current rotation is -90, and you want it to rotate one turn clockwise ? I tried -90 then 270, but it seems to not be working in IE.

Comment: Well, if you rotate something 360 degrees it will stay in the same place. If you want to see the rotation you need to rotate by adding 1 degree (or any other degree number) until you reach 360. After that you'll complete the whole circle.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you also need to remember to put in the "from" initial concrete values, otherwise the +/- direction sign won't behave well.