# I am having trouble with getting my image to rotate anti-clockwise

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I've trouble with getting my image to rotate anti-clockwise i feel i may be missing a simple step, here is my code : please fix this code.

```
.image {     
    position: absolute;     
    top: 30%;     
    left: 37%;     
    width: 430px;     
    height: 430px;     
    margin:210px 0 0 -60px;    
    -webkit-animation:spin 75s linear infinite;     
    -moz-animation:spin 75s linear infinite;     
    animation:spin 75s linear infinite; 
} 
.redline {     
    position: absolute;    
     top: 30%;     
    left: 37%;     
    width: 430px;     
    height: 430px;     
    margin:210px 0 0 -60px;     
    -webkit-animation:spin 35s linear infinite;     
    -moz-animation:spin 35s linear infinite;     
    animation:spin 35s linear infinite; 
}  
@-moz-keyframes spin { 
    100% { transform-moz-transform: spin(-720deg); } 
}
```

Comment: i wanted the image to rotate anti-clockwise and for it to constantly rotate from its centre

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine direction of rotation in CSS3 transitions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072869/how-to-determine-direction-of-rotation-in-css3-transitions)

Answer (score 0):

To rotate a image or div `rotate(180deg)` works. you can use any value in the place of `180`. see snippet its working

```css
.image {
     width:50%;
     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s ease-in;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); 
     -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
```

```html
<img class="image" src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/conquer/assets/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" />
```